# Next Js Router.push is not a function error

Tags: reactjs, next.js

When I try to redirect using Router.push() I get the following error:

```
TypeError: next_router__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_3__.Router.push is not a function
```

I am trying to migrate from create-react-app to next js.

```
const redirectUser = () => {
        if (true) {
            Router.push('/');
        }
    };
```

Comment: Did you try import Router by: `import Router from 'next/router`?

Comment: Yes I did import

Comment: Hah! I am actually following your udemy course mern-react-node-aws. Without this answer I was going to spend several thousands of years looking for the source of this error XD What a surprise to find the answer was provided by none other than Ryan Dhungel himself ^^ Thanks for all you do! Your course is helping me A LOT

Answer (score 58):

I had to import like so:

```
// works
import Router from "next/router";
// dont
import { Router } from "next/router";
```

Comment: That saved my day! Wouldn't have noticed it

Comment: Thanks a load, man. Was frustrated after giving my all for the continuous 5 hours.

Comment: This still works in 2022. Thank you.

Comment: The auto-importer defaults to the bad import. grrrr.

Answer (score 4):

Don't add curly bracket while importing Router from next/router

Use this:

```
import Router from "next/router";
```

Answer (score 1):

The Router module is available only client-side

Comment: so you mean one would need useEffect() from react

Answer (score 1):

you have to take into account when you use next.js that the redirects should be in `getInitialProps` method in order to avoid unnecessary render components.

for example

```
const MyComponent = ()=>{
  return <tag> {/* ... */} </tag>
}
MyComponent.getInitialProps = ({res}) => {
  if (res) { 
    /* serve-side */
    res.writeHead(302, {
    Location: 'http://example.com'
  })
  res.end()
  } else {      
   /* client-side */
    Router.push('http://example.com')
  }
  return {}
}
```