# Nextjs Router.push vs href

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

For Routing to some page on click, I can achieve it in two ways

```
import Router from 'next/router'  

<button onClick={() => Router.push('/about')}>
    <a>Go to About</a>
</button>
```

And

```
 <button>
     <a href="/about">Go to About</a>
 </button>
```

Which one is the best practice in Nextjs?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54968574/next-js-router-push-is-not-a-function-error

Answer (score 2):

`a` tag inside `button` is not allowed in semantic html, both of them are interactive elements.

For links, Next provides [`Link` component](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next/link) that accepts `a` tag as a child.
For buttons, use `<button onClick={() => Router.push('/about')}>text</button>` without `a`.

Comment: Got it, but which one is the best practice?

Comment: It depends if you need a link or just use action, links are better for SEO

Answer (score 0):

The best way to create links between pages is to use your nextjs package.

```
import Link from "next/link";
```

Then use it like that

```
<Link href={'/'} params={'id': 1}>
  <a>link</a>
</.Link>
```

if useing node js router href linked by name route

Answer (score 0):

For the best user experience I would suggest a third option / best practice:

```
import Link from "next/link";

<Link href={"/within/your/page"} passHref>
  <button>go</button> // or any other element
</Link>
```

pre NextJS 10 if your path had dynamic segments you would need to pass "as" also like:

```
import Link from "next/link";

<Link href={"/review/[id]"} as={"/review/12"} passHref>
  <button>go</button> // or any other element
</Link>
```

The Link Component / the router.push enables client side navigation. This makes navigating your website a lot faster.

you can read more on this here:

- https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next/link
- https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next/router